# tar.gz won't extract on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, compression, tar

Why is this not working?

```
sh-3.2# tar -xzf postgresql-7.4.28.tar.gz 
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Comment: Should probably be on superuser.com.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try `gunzip` on the file, if you have it. Maybe you'll see a more informative error message.

Comment: what i gunzip or tar -xz the process just runs forever.

Comment: @harmzl, did you try downloading it again?  As many people below have mentioned, you probably have a corrupt file.

Comment: @Carl: As he said as a comment to my answer, checksums seem to match, so it's *very* unlikely to be corrupt.

Answer (score 6):

That means it's not actually a gzipped file.  Use the `file` utility to find out what it really is, then use the appropriate flags to `tar` to unpack it.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the postgresql folks put misleading file names on their distributed stuff. Another possibility would be that the file was somehow damaged in transit. Did you know that MS Word can open (and mangle) binary files? I once had a colleague who did that a lot, and then wondered why his .EXEs weren't executing :)

Comment: @Carl, if it was mangled in transit, it's still not a gzip file anymore.

Comment: It might be whatever program/browser you downloaded it in figured out it was gzip encoded and unpacked it - it's not an uncommon thing.

Comment: i ended up downloading a different version, which worked fine

Comment: Strange... anyway, glad it works now

Answer (score 3):

What likely happened is your browser decompressed the file in transit. This can happen because gzip is one of the ways HTTP servers will send data to your browser, so it will uncompress it in order for it to display properly.

You could try `file` command to see what it is. Or, alternatively, just skip to the chase and try unpacking it as such: `tar xf postgresql-7.4.28.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if the file size and MD5 sum is correct, maybe the downloaded file is corrupt or some HTML error. [This site](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-announce/2010-04/msg00005.php) says the MD5 sum should be `fed173049eda38ce6c3348e277fabec7`. There's a sha1sum, too, if you prefer this.

If this is correct, the file is not a correct .tar.gz archive and you should use some other programs to detect the filetype or decompress it, but I doubt this.

EDIT: Trying under Windows using 7-Zip, it works perfectly. Results in a TAR file 54.298.624 bytes in size and the final extraction leads to 2.761 files and 309 folders... perhaps you should try using [p7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) for Mac OS X. If this works, perhaps there is something wrong with your tar/gzip and you should try to reinstall the packages.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the postgresql-7.4.28.tar.gz  archive (having the MD5 fed173049eda38ce6c3348e277fabec7 mentioned above) using the original poster's command:

tar -xzf postgresql-7.4.28.tar.gz

...so I expect that we'll hear that the MD5 doesn't match.